# Android Unity Controls

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, mobile-application

I am trying to convert my PC game code in unity to android and I am stuck on the controls change. Please help!

This is the code:

Getting the state of rocket.

```
enum State { Dying, Alive, Transcending }
State state = State.Alive;

// Update is called once per frame

void Update()
{
    if (state == State.Alive)
    {
        RespondToThrustInput();
        RespondToRotateInput();
    }
}
```

When the rocket collides with anything it checks whether it's friendly or not before changing its state from alive to dead.

```
private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    if (state != State.Alive) { return; }
    switch (collision.gameObject.tag)
    {
        case "Friendly":
            break;
        case "Finish":
            state = State.Transcending;
            audioSource.Stop();
            audioSource.PlayOneShot(finishgame);
            finishgameParticles.Play();
            Invoke("LoadNextScene", levelloaddelay);
            break;
        default:
            state = State.Dying;
            audioSource.Stop();
            audioSource.PlayOneShot(death);
            deathParticles.Play();
            Invoke("LoadFirstScene", levelloaddelay);
            break;
     }
}

private void LoadFirstScene()
{
       SceneManager.LoadScene(9);
}
```

Loading next scene using build index.

```
private void LoadNextScene()
{
    if (nextscenetoload > 7)
    {
        nextscenetoload = 0;
    }
    SceneManager.LoadScene(nextscenetoload);
}
```

Space for ignition or force and audio sources for playing sound effects.

```
private void RespondToThrustInput()
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        ApplyThrust();
    }
    else
    {
        audioSource.Stop();
        mainengineParticles.Stop();
    }
}
```

Apply thrust is the method I wrote with the logic of the rocket thrust.

```
private void ApplyThrust()
{
    rigidbody.AddRelativeForce(Vector3.up * mainThrust * Time.deltaTime);
    if (!audioSource.isPlaying)
        audioSource.PlayOneShot(mainengine);

    mainengineParticles.Play();
}
```

Rotation of the rocket or Left and right. Here I am trying to rotate the rocket using the A and D keys

```
void RespondToRotateInput()
{
    float rotationThisFrame = rcsThrust * Time.deltaTime;
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
    {
        rigidbody.freezeRotation = true;
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward * rotationThisFrame);
        rigidbody.freezeRotation = false;
    }
    else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
    {
        rigidbody.freezeRotation = true;
        transform.Rotate(-Vector3.forward * rotationThisFrame);
        rigidbody.freezeRotation = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For PC games there is a keyboard to use to control, but for the android there are touches, you have to verify if there is a touch on the screen, like this:

```
    if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
        //do something
    }
```

also you need more work to determine where the touch is located and do you customizations... or in case you're not interested about this input handling, you can use some assets from Unity Assets Store to cover this part for you.

check this link for more information about touch control in Unity documentation:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetTouch.html

Comment: yeah i did all of that but what im asking is i made buttons for these touch controls and there is a thrust button so when player holds that button the applythrust method should work but how to implement it? like input.touchcount what will be that?!